# When added JSONObject method, Limited Json in Android

Tags: android, json

I want develop android application for one website. I read website posts from `json` and show its in `RecyclerView` every 10 posts. 
But i have strange problem! when added this line in my codes, `json` and `RecyclerView` has limited and show 5 post instance of 10 posts!
**code :**

```
JSONObject imagesPair=images.getJSONObject("martial-frontpage-blog");
```

when added this line limited for 5 post, when delete this line it's ok and show 10 posts!
**Json Link:** [Json link](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&count=10&page=1)

**AsyncTask codes:**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=1");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "page=1")
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);

                            JSONObject images=postObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject imagesPair=images.getJSONObject("martial-frontpage-blog");

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(
                                    postObject.getInt("id"),
                                    postObject.getString("title"),
                                    postObject.getString("content"),
                                    postObject.getString("thumbnail")));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i fix this problem and when added above code, show 10 posts and run success application ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how to use Gson here

first, add in your `build.gradle` this

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    //your all other dependencies
}
```

second, create class `PostsResponse` and write in it

```
package your.package.here;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PostsResponse {
    private static final String DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL = "put your default image url here";
    public static class Post {
        @SerializedName("id")
        private int mId;
        @SerializedName("title")
        private String mTitle;
        @SerializedName("content")
        private String mContent;
        @SerializedName("thumbnail")
        private String mThumbnail;
        @SerializedName("thumbnail_images")
        private Images mImages;

        public static class Images {
            @SerializedName("martial-frontpage-blog")
            private String mMartialFrontpageBlogUrl;

            public String getMartialFrontpageBlogImage() {
                return TextUtils.isEmpty(mMartialFrontpageBlogUrl) ?
                        DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL :
                        mMartialFrontpageBlogUrl;
            }
        }

        public int getId() {
            return mId;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return mContent;
        }

        public String getThumbnail() {
            return mThumbnail;
        }
        public String getMartialFrontpageBlogImage() {
            return mImages.getMartialFrontpageBlogImage();
        }
    }
    @SerializedName("posts")
    private ArrayList<Post> mPosts;

    public ArrayList<Post> getPosts() {
        return mPosts;
    }
}
```

and change part of your `MainDataInfo` from

```
       if (ou_response != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                JSONArray postsArray = postObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                    JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                    int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                    String title = postObject.getString("title");
                    Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                    Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);

                    JSONObject images=postObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                    JSONObject imagesPair=images.getJSONObject("martial-frontpage-blog");

                    //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                    infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(
                            postObject.getInt("id"),
                            postObject.getString("title"),
                            postObject.getString("content"),
                            postObject.getString("thumbnail")));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

to this new one

```
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(ou_response)) {
            try {
                PostsResponse postsResponse = new Gson().fromJson(ou_response, PostsResponse.class);

                infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
                for (PostsResponse.Post post : postsResponse.getPosts()) {
                    infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(
                            post.getId(),
                            post.getTitle(),
                            post.getContent(),
                            post.getThumbnail())
                    );
                    //// TODO: 26.04.16 use post.getMartialFrontpageBlogImage()
                    //// as you want here
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

don't forget to properly fill `DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL` and package
and see `TODO` section
feel free to add new fields to `Post` class and provide getters for them

THE END )

Comment: WoW!!!!!!!!!!! you areeeeeeee best man, thank you my dear friend. thanks you very much <3

Answer (score 0):

"post" with index 5 in your server response has no "martial-frontpage-blog" in "thumbnail_images", so your parsing cycle simply stops and drops exception.

to fix it - use [optJSONObject();](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONObject(java.lang.String))

```
imagesPair = images.optJSONObject("...");
```

and check it for

```
null
```

Answer (score 0):

one else moment )
fix your cycle from

```
for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++) {
```

in your current realization cycle stops work by exception )

Comment: Replace this for code with my code, when write this code :                                 `infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(
                                        postObject.getInt("id"),
                                        postObject.getString("title"),
                                        postObject.getString("content"),
                                        postObject.getString(imagesPair.getString("url"))));` not show me any post :(

Comment: How can i fit this problem? i really need this :(

Comment: ohh use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) it will solve all your problems with parsing server response )

Comment: tnx man, i am amateur and i can't use Gson. can you help me and send me code for this asyncTask? please

Comment: ok, i'll try write some, but answer first - do you use Android Studio?

Comment: I'll post it as another answer